# Configuração do PHP-FPM para 2gb de ram?

Tags: php, amazon-aws, php-fpm

Tenho a seguinte instancia na AWS:

> t2.small (Variable ECUs, 1 vCPUs, 2.5 GHz, Intel Xeon Family, 2 GiB memory, EBS only)

E no meu log de erro está aparecendo

```
WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (8), consider raising it
```

Minha configuração está assim:

```
pm                        = dynamic
pm.max_children           = 8
pm.start_servers          = 3
pm.min_spare_servers      = 3
pm.max_spare_servers      = 6
pm.max_requests           = 200
pm.process_idle_timeout   = 10s;
;pm.status_path           = /status
;ping.path                = /ping
;ping.response            = pong

request_terminate_timeout = 200s
request_slowlog_timeout   = 60s

php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
```

Pensei apenas em dobrar o max_children, mas queria ter um ajuste mais apropriado para a instancia que uso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, o PHP-FPM atingiu o limite máximo de processos filhos.

Atualmente meu limite está configurado para 8 processos, mas como a máquina tem 2gb, daria para aumentar o limite até 16.

> A conta: 2048mb memória instancia / 128mb memória por requisição = 16

```
pm.max_children = 16
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
```